# How to limit property returned after save?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to return the saved object as the request response, but I don't want whole object returned by `Model.save()` function, it's returning more information than I want, like `_id`, `__v`.

My request code is like this:

```
function insertUser(req, res) {
   const userName = req.Body.name;

      User.save({ name : userName })
         .then(r => {  
            res.send(r);
         });
}
```

It's returning fallowing `JSON` to me:

```
{
    _id: 590f529976aa6142d91870b7,
    name: 'blablabla'
    __v: 4
}
```

How can I set it to return only `{ name : 'blablabla' }`?

Comment: Why not just do `res.send({ name: r.name })` ?

Comment: God! Why I didn't think this way! That's work for me. But can I configure by `mongoose` to return only `name`? Just for curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write method for this:

Add this method in your user schema:
With this method you can control what you return to the client

```
userSchema.methods.getPublicFields = function() {
  return {
    name: this.name
  };
};
```

and use it like this

```
User.save({ name : userName })
     .then(r => {  
        res.send(r.getPublicFields);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// transform for sending as json
function omitPrivate(doc, obj) {
    delete obj.__v;
    delete obj.id;
    return obj;
}

// schema options
var options = { toJSON: { transform: omitPrivate } };

// schema
var schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
}, options);
```